# Codeigniter and composer, class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have installed with composer this library:
[mailchimp](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api)

to my codeigniter 2.x project. I am calling the library from the controller:

```
$MailChimp = new \MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
```

but the error is:

```
Class 'MailChimp' not found in /var/www/CI/application/controllers/auth.php
```

where auth is the controller from where I am calling MailChimp class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just need to switch the class to its full name:

```
$MailChimp = new \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
```

Or alternatively, `use` the namespace before initializing the MailChimp object as the [wrapper's documentation](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api#examples) suggests:

```
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
$MailChimp = new MailChimp('abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123-us1');
```